# How to convert varchar to date for ordering in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has a column `CreatedDate` that is of type `varchar(100)`. The rows for that columns are:

```
CreatedDate
--------------
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 7, 2015
March 10, 2015
```

If I do the following query, the date aren't ordering correctly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Db].[dbo].[Table1] 
ORDER BY [CD] ASC
```

I see the following:

```
CreatedDate
---------------
March 10, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 6, 2015
March 7, 2015
```

How can I cast the column so the ordering statement works correctly?

Comment: The rows are ordered **absolutely correctly** - for a `varchar`. That's what you get from using the **wrong datatype** - if you have a date - store it as a `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` !! See also: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: It needed to be a varchar format for use somewhere else. Thanks for the critiquing :)

Comment: You can *always* easily convert anything to a string - there's really no point in storing numbers or dates as **string**...

Comment: You might consider a computed column against the true date value if you need a string version immediately available for consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it can all be safely converted to date or datetime:

```
CAST(CD AS DATE)
```

If not you'd have to split the string up and make it a date manually.

Comment: Easy and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `ORDER BY` clause to:

```
ORDER BY TRY_PARSE(CreatedDate AS DATE) ASC;
```

If the `CreatedDate` column contains values that aren't valid dates, [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) returns NULL for sort evaluation instead of throwing an error message.

If you have control over the table definition, change the column data type to [DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx). You won't have to jump through hoops for sorting, invalid date ranges will be prevented at insert, and less space is required.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4889e/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Cast` or `Convert` function to convert the `varchar` data to `Date` then use it in `order by`

```
SELECT *
FROM   [Db].[dbo].[Table1]
ORDER  BY Cast([CD] AS DATE) ASC
```

If you use proper `datatype(date)` such problems can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [Db].[dbo].[Table1]
ORDER  BY CONVERT(DATETIME,[CD],105) ASC
```